# Finding the unmatched rows in one List<T> object from another List<T> object where Id matches using Linq C#

Tags: c#, excel, list, linq

I have an Excel file with the set of records and I have a database called `UserTable` with a set of records. I'm doing is I changed both the database and Excel into lists and compared both the records with the field called `UserId`.

Now I want to update `list1` (`usertable` from the database) with list2 (from the Excel sheet). If `UserId` field matches in both lists and any other field doesn't match, it has to be updated in `list1`.

I tried this code:

```
public void Update(List<UserTable> users, List<UserTable> mappeddata)
{
    var valuetoupdate = mappeddata.IntersectBy(users.Select(y => y.UserId), y => y.UserId, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    var rowsToUpdate = valuetoupdate.Except(users, new UserTableEqualityComparer());
}

public class UserTableEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<UserTable>
{
    public bool Equals(UserTable x, UserTable y)
    {
         if (x == null || y == null)
             return false;
         else 
             return
                  (string.Equals(x.ManagerUserId, y.ManagerUserId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && 
                   string.Equals(x.Department, y.Department, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && 
                   string.Equals(x.Title, y.Title, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
                    ...//rest of the field
                  );
    }
    public int GetHashCode(UserTable obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 23 + (obj.ManagerUserId?.ToLower().GetHashCode() ?? 0);
            hash = hash * 23 + (obj.Department?.ToLower().GetHashCode() ?? 0);
            hash = hash * 23 + (obj.Title?.ToLower().GetHashCode() ? 0);
            ...//rest of the field
            return hash;
        }
    } 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You've tagged SQL Server and Excel, but it seems the solution itself you are looking for doesn't require experts in these areas?

Comment: i will correct it,but i have changed my excel and database into list objects

Comment: What are you using for database access? Is there any chance that it is EF?

Comment: Yes I am using EFcore

Comment: What question are you asking? You've made a bunch of statements, but no questions.

Comment: I'm generating update statement for that i used this code but i haven't got the desired output from this

Comment: @Sapris - Yes, but what are you asking us?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would change the source data into dictionary:

```cs
List<UserTable> mappeddata = ...; 
var dict = mappeddata
   .GroupBy(t => t.UserId) // or .GroupBy(t => t.UserId, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First()); // possibly need some logic to handle duplicates
```

If you are using EF Core one option would be to just rely on it's change tracker (though it will perform case-sensitive comparisons):

```cs
var fromDb = _ctx.UserTable
    .Where(t => dict.Keys.Contains(t.UserId)) // no need to fetch all users, fetch only existing in the dictionary
    .ToList();
foreach (var ut in fromDb)
{
    var source = dict[ut.UserId];
    // ... map data
}
_ctx.SaveChanges(); // will update only data with changed values
```

EF Core should update data only if it has actually changed.

If you need to use case-insensitive comparisons I till would not go with the comparer approach.

```cs
var toUpdate = fromDb
    .Where(t =>
    {
        var source = dict[t.UserId];
        return !string.Equals(t.ManagerUserId, source.ManagerUserId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
               || !string.Equals(t.Department, source.Department, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    });
foreach (var ut in toUpdate)
{
    var source = dict[ut.UserId];
    // ... map data
}
```

If you want to stick to managing 2 lists then you can modify the second approach a bit:

```cs
var toUpdate = users
    .Where(t => dict.ContainsKey(t.UserId)) // filter out not present in the data
    .Where(t =>
    {
        var source = dict[t.UserId];
        return !string.Equals(t.ManagerUserId, source.ManagerUserId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
               || !string.Equals(t.Department, source.Department, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: can you please explain, I don't get it. are you trying to update the database directly or updating the list. What I am doing is, i have converted database(usertable) into  list1 and excel into list2, and storing the changes in list3. i'm generating the update statement to update the datebase from list3. Thanks.

Comment: @Sapris EF Core uses change tracking so if you have fetched entity via EF Core (with tracking enabled) and then changed fields in those entities - EF will only propagate the changes only of data has actually changed. There is no need to use `list3`, but you can if you want you can build it from `toUpdate` in the second snippet (see the update).

Comment: I tried the last one but i got 0 as output. Its not working

Comment: @Sapris please provide a full [mre] (so it can be compiled and run and show the problem)

Comment: I have changed my code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you're not doing something simple like this?

```
public void Update(List<UserTable> users, List<UserTable> mappeddata)
{
    var rowsToUpdate =
        from m in mappeddata
        join u in users on m.UserId equals u.UserId
        where
            m.ManagerUserId != u.ManagerUserId
            || m.Department != u.Department
            || m.Title != u.Title
        select m;
}
```

I know I haven't done this by ignoring case, you should get the idea.